# NSBezierPath: how to invert the clip path?

Tags: cocoa, nsview, clip, nsbezierpath

I am drawing a rounded image in the centre of my custom view by creating a rounded `NSBezierPath` and adding it to the clipping region of the graphics context.  This is working well, but I'm wondering if I can improve the performance of drawing the background of the view (the area outside of the rounded centred image) but inverting this clip and performing the background draw (an `NSGradient` fill).

Can anyone suggest a method of inverting a clip path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't improve the drawing performance of the background by doing this. If anything, using a more complex clipping path will slow down drawing.

If you want to draw objects over a background without significant overhead of redrawing the background, you could use Core Animation layers as I explained in [my answer to this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372715/can-i-use-calayer-to-speed-up-view-rendering/9377565#9377565)

Comment: Thank you - that's good to know.  I am restricting the background drawing to times when `dirtyRect` isn't wholly within my image and I will look into `CALayer` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of performance, this question comes first when you try to invert clip.

So if that's what you're looking for:
**[Using NSBezierPath addClip - How to invert clip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41219817/893809)**